# Products of matrices over non-fields

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, modules

While trying to find structures that would solve a problem I have to make a replayable detective type of book, I have run into a set of properties that would solve my problems, if only I could find examples of objects that have such properties, and this led me to writing this question.

Let $X \in \mathcal{M}_{m \times n} (M)$, and $B$ be an $n \times m$ matrix over some group $G$.

If I believe correctly, the product $XB$ would require $G$ to be an $M$-module to be well defined, and the resulting matrix $C$ would be in $\mathcal{M}_{m \times m} (G)$. Each $c_{i,j}$ would then be of the form $$c_{i,j} = \sum_{k=1}^m x_{i,k}b_{k,j}.$$

What are the necessary conditions for the product $XB$ to ''uniquely define $C$ on the left''? That is, if $X_1B = X_2B$, then $X_1 = X_2$.

Is there a way to also have $c_{i,j}$ to be uniquely determined by the sum that defines it? By that I mean, is there a way to have $\sum_{p=1}^m a_{i,p}b_{p,j} = \sum_{q=1}^m a_{i,q}b_{q,j}$ if, and only if, $a_{i,p} = a_{i,q}$ and $b_{p,j} = b_{q,j}$ for all $q \in \{1,\ldots,m\}$.

I imagine this uniqueness would pose conditions onto both $X$ and $G$, although I don't even know if it possible to have this while still having the first condition.

If the question is too vague to be understood, I would love to try to reformulate it giving additional context.

Comment: The phrase "uniquely define $C$ on the left" seems infelicitous, if what you mean is that $X_1 B = X_2 B$ should imply $X_1 = X_2$.  The phrase would convey to me that $C$ is determined by $X$ and $B$, taken together, and this would follow were the expression $\sum_{k=1}^n x_{i,k} b_{k,j}$ well-defined.  It is of course possible to define "matrix multiplication" over non-fields, e.g. taking products of integer-valued matrices.  But perhaps this sort of example does not illustrate your desired application.

Comment: I see the product is well defined then, given $G$ is an $M$-module. As for the ''uniquely define $C$ on the left'', I agree it was not necessary, given that I explained what I needed, but didn't have a good phrase to convey it.

As for the second condition, is it complete gibberish or are there examples of groups (they would have to be non-abelian I assume) that would satisfy it?

Comment: I think when you say $G$, a group, is "an $M$-module", you imply that $G$ is an abelian group.  Incidentally the summation index $k$ ought to be from $1$ to $n$ in you matrix multiplication formula.

Comment: Oops! Guess I missed that implication. I suppose there is no way to have property 2 then.

Comment: Perhaps you have in mind a definite ring $M$, and some idea of whether $m\le n$ or vice versa.  For example, we could think about $M=\mathbb Z$ and $G$ an abelian group, and proceed to consider the problem in more specific ways.

Comment: I do have a restriction I would like to impose into $M$ being $Z/Z_2$, and $G$ being finite and non-abelian, because I really needed the second condition to be true. I needed some examples of $G$ that would satisfy the second condition, but I have no idea how to approach the problem. Having read into near-rings, I don't think my math abilities are enough to understand them very well.